# Error with JavaFX when aplying custom themes to ChoiceBox

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

This is not a specific problem.

Open NetBeans, create a new FXML Project, open SceneBuilder and add a new `ChoiceBox`.

Close SceneBuilder, run project. Choice box is showing up, no problems.

The problem is when I apply a CSS stylesheet like [Win7Glass](https://github.com/GreggSetzer/JavaFX-CSS-Themes/raw/master/win7glass.css), or use AeroFX style. For my surprise, `ChoiceBox` is now disappeared. In buttons and other controls it works well.

But if I apply the AquaFX style, it works well.

And also, when I choose the win7glass CSS in SceneBuilder, it applies perfectly to the `ChoiceBox`.

My application has a theme switcher and when you select these themes, the choiceboxes disappear.

Screenshots: [click here for images](http://manudp.ga/portfolio/javafx-dude-stackoverflow/)

The core of the problem is that when applying the AeroFX or win7glss themes the ChoiceBoxes disappears. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the FXML file on SceneBuilder, for AeroFX, win7.css doesn't contain the class `choice-box`, you see the default modena style applied.

But the problem with AeroFX is it doen't have a customized `ChoiceBox` control, and when you apply in code `AeroFX.style()` there is no skin `AeroChoiceBoxSkin`, and with no skin to apply, it 'disappears'.

While in AquaFX there is an `AquaChoiceBoxSkin` class, and it works when you style the application with `AquaFx.style()`.

**EDIT**

If you look at how `AeroFX.style()` works in the source code, this is what it's doing:

```
public static void style(){
    Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(
        AeroFX.class.getResource("win7.css").toExternalForm());
}
```

According to the JavaDoc for `setUserAgentStylesheet`:

> Set the user agent stylesheet used by the whole application. This is used to provide default styling for all ui controls and other nodes.

The problem with this approach is with the controls not included in win7.css, like `ChoiceBox`: They keep their default skin (`com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ChoiceBoxSkin`), with their default style selectors like `open-button`, `arrow`, ... When the skin is applied, these are not found in the css file, no style is applied, and the control is not visible (though it is displayed).

On the contrary, when you open the FXML file with Scene Builder, you're not overriding the user agent stylesheet, you are just adding a stylesheet that may override the default one just on the style classes provided, and keeping the default one (modena) for those controls not included. That's why you see the `ChoiceBox` but with the default modena style.

Try to run your application without calling `AeroFX.style()`, you'll see the choice box with modena style and if you have buttons, textfields, checkboxes,... those will have windows 7 style.

Comment: thanks for your answer. That's the main problem. It occurs with AeroFX and Win7Glass CSS. I tried right now and when applying AeroFX in SceneBuilder, it does shhow up the Win7 style in ChoiceBoxes. It's very starnge as you see. Screenshot: [link](http://manudp.ga/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/scenebuilder.png)

Comment: I've edited my answer, to explain the reason why `AeroFX` doesn't work with your app.

Comment: look at the screenshot on my first comment. I konw AeroFX does not include the choice button skin, but win7glass CSS includes it and it works well over SceneBuilder. However, when I apply the win7glass CSS to my app using the same command, it doesn't show up well(but it applies), so your answer is ok. Here you have the effects:[click here](http://manudp.ga/stackover-flow-queation-part3/)

Comment: I have the exact same result for win7glass.css with Scene Builder and running the application. Note `-fx-focused-base` is not defined under modena.css (that's why you don't see the arrow), so you need to add this at the beginning of the file: `.root { -fx-text-base-color: #000000; -fx-focused-base: -fx-base; }`.